# Laravel 5.3 migration

Tags: laravel-5

I just upgrade to Laravel to 5.x and using `"jenssegers/Date": "^3.0"`.

So while migrating, there seems to be an error:

> [ErrorException] Declaration of
>   Jenssegers\Date\Date::diffForHumans(Carbon\Carbon $since = NULL,
>   $absolute = false) should be compatible with
>   Carbon\Carbon::diffForHumans(Carbon\Carbon $other = NULL, $absolute =
>   false, $short = false)

Please suggest what can be done to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your problem is with this package [jenssegers/date](https://github.com/jenssegers/date/blob/master/src/Date.php). As you can see `Jenssegers\Date` extends Carbon and on line 104

```
public function diffForHumans(Carbon $since = null, $absolute = false, $short = false)
```

has different implementation than Carbon

```
public function diffForHumans(Carbon $other = null, $absolute = false)
```

The way to overcome this is to redefine the method on either class, which is not recommended because they are both within Vendor folder. So I guess your options would be to either open up an issue on [jassegers/date](https://github.com/jenssegers/date/issues), or try not to use that package (write your own replacement if you don't use it that much).

The problem can be even more difficult if you don't have this package in your projects Composer.json, but some other package you use has `jassegers/date` as a dependency. You can check this in the Vendor in Composer.json of each of your projects dependencies. In this case you might consider using a different package than the one that uses `jassegers/date` as a dependency, at least until it's updated.

Perhaps someone has better suggestions, this is just of the top of my head..

P.S. Just remembered.. you can also fork `jassegers/date` if you're using it directly in your Composer.json, and change the method implementation by yourself and use that forked version until the genuine one is fixed. If you use it indirectly (some other package you use has this as a dependency), that would be a bit more complicated, meaning you would have to fork packages all the way down until you get to `jassegers/date`. This would be quite tedious work, but should fix the problem temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare [current Carbon source code](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/Carbon.php#L2794):

```
public function diffForHumans(Carbon $other = null, $absolute = false, $short = false)
```

with [current jenssegers/Date source code](https://github.com/jenssegers/date/blob/master/src/Date.php#L106):

```
public function diffForHumans(Carbon $since = null, $absolute = false, $short = false)
```

you see there shouldn't be any issues. It seems that you're using newer Carbon than jenssegers/Date, and versions are incompatible. You need to update your jenssegers/Date.

[3.2.8 seems to be the latest release](https://github.com/jenssegers/date/releases), I'd test going there. [3.2.3 seems to be the first version including the third parameter](https://github.com/jenssegers/date/blob/v3.2.3/src/Date.php), with [this commit](https://github.com/jenssegers/date/commit/7c4dd4f5d7557981b752f468ee876809f8438a6e):

> Carbon\Carbon::diffForHumans(Carbon\Carbon $other = NULL, $absolute =
>   false, $short = false) has a new third argument and lack of it in
>   Jenssegers\Date\Date::diffForHumans is not playing nicely.

so your version needs to be at least that.